# Custom allocator doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: c#, video, directx, directshow

I writing a program using a custom allocator that allow to display my directshow video capture to a directx texture.
Since I'm running my program on Windows 7 it display a white frame instead of my video.

If I configure my VMR9 filter to display on a control it works fine.

Does anyone have a clue to solve this problem?

Comment: This is too little information. Did you try the debug DirectX settings?

Comment: Any chance of seeing some code?

Comment: Yes I will send some code and start the bounty again later. Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself using *DirectX Control Panel* to enable *Debug mode*. I realized that I wasn't doing the thing in the right order when setting the allocator. Here is a portion of my code:

```
filterConfig.SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode.Renderless);
// QueryInterface on the VMR-9 filter for the IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify9 interface.
IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify9 san = (IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify9)_vmr9;
// Call the IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify9::AdviseSurfaceAllocator method and pass in a pointer to your allocator-presenter's IVMRSurfaceAllocator9 method.
san.AdviseSurfaceAllocator(IntPtr.Zero, allocator);
// Call your allocator-presenter's IVMRSurfaceAllocator9::AdviseNotify method and pass in a pointer to the VMR-9 filter's IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify9 interface.
allocator.AdviseNotify(san);
// Change mixer prefs AFTER settings the allocator in order to support YUV mixing (best performance)
IVMRMixerControl9 mixerControl = (IVMRMixerControl9)_vmr9;
VMR9MixerPrefs prefs;
mixerControl.GetMixingPrefs(out prefs);
prefs &= ~VMR9MixerPrefs.RenderTargetMask;
prefs |= VMR9MixerPrefs.RenderTargetYUV;
mixerControl.SetMixingPrefs(prefs);
```

Comment: The last setting with the mixer saves me.
I render GUI along with video frame from VMR9 in the main render loop and flickering occur. After puting the mixer setting in and no more flickering.

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow with custom Allocator Presenter in vmr9, does work in Windows 7. You probably have something broken in your code.
Try clearing the frame before drawing to another color, red for example. If you see red, means that you don't draw the frame correctly. If you don't, means that you didn't do something correctly.

I would advice you to check your locking mechanism because your custom AP is accessed from 3-5 threads at the same time.